# Proving $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N; f(n) = n+1$ is not surjective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that the function $$f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N; f(n) = n+1$$ is not bijective.

So I know that we can prove it is injective because we can suppose or let $n_1$ and $n_2$ are natural numbers with $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$, then by definition of f, that means $n_1+1=n_2+1.$ When subtracting 1 from both sides we know that $n_1=n_2$.

How do I prove it is not surjective? I know that for any natural number we put into the function that it would just be plus 1, but how do we prove that? It is one-to-one.

EDIT: So I think this proves it.
$$f(0) = -1$$
So -1 is not in the natural numbers set, how do I correctly write this for a proof?

Comment: What is preimage of 1 under $f$?provided $\mathbb N$ starts with 1

Comment: Ah a knight of the round table, Sir Jective of Mapping.  Infinite sets always have maps that are injective but not surjective.

Comment: Nope, $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: By the standard definition, $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$, so $f(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the least element of $\Bbb N$? (Can you see why that's relevant?)

Comment: According to our professor the least element of ℕ is 1. I would think it would only be relevant if it started with 0.

Comment: What would you have to do to show that $f$ **is** surjective? (It isn't, but bear with me.)

Comment: You would have to show that it has multiple x answers for f(x). like x^2

Comment: No. You seem to be thinking of *injectivity*. To prove *surjectivity* of a function $g:A\to B,$ you must show that for every $b\in B,$ there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $g(a)=b.$ How does this translate to this problem?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are saying I think, please check my updated question.

Comment: You're very nearly there. Here's a problem, though: since $0$ isn't in $\Bbb N,$ then there's no such thing as $f(0),$ and even if there were, we'd have $f(0)=0+1=1$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

If it were surjective there would be an $n$ such that $n+1=0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If your natural numbers are with 0, what is $f^{-1}(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Given any $n \in \mathbb N$, is it the case that $n - 1 \in \mathbb N$? If so, then it's surjective. But it isn't, so what's our counterexample going to be?

Answer (score 1):

To understand surjectivity, you have to distinguish between the *range* of a function and the *codomain* of a function.

Suppose $D$ is the domain of a function.  A value $y$ is in the range of a function iff $\exists x ~~ x\in D \text{ and } y = f(x)$.

The codomain of a function, on the other hand, is whatever you say it is.  It is usually written as $\text{domain} \to \text{codomain}$.

So for example, consider $f(x) = 2x, \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$.  The domain is natural numbers.  The range is even numbers.  The codomain is real numbers.

If the codomain and the range are the same set, then the function is surjective.  Otherwise it is not.

So for your problem, figure out what the range is, figure out what the codomain is, then determine if they are equal.

---

Sometimes the term "image" is used instead of range.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Which number is such that $f(n)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove surjectivity is to show that the range of the function and it's codomain are equal. In stating that $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ we are told that the function maps the domain $ \mathbb{N}$ onto the codomain $ \mathbb{N}$. So the the codomain is $ \mathbb{N}$. What is the range? The range is all the natural numbers except $1$, $R(f) =  \mathbb{N} \ \{1\}$. Since the range does not equal the codomain the function is not surjective.

To put it another way:
Recall that a function is said to be surjective iff for every element in the codomain there exists at least one element in the domain that is its preimage.
Consider $\{1\}\in  \mathbb{N}$
Note that $f^{-1}(1)=\{\}$
Since $\{1\}$ belongs to the codomain but has no preimage in the domain it follows that $f(x)$ is not surjective.